# WSL intergration with ADS login credentials

Tags: ansible, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed WSL ubantu flavor, Installed Ansible and sutable linux packages on it. Thought of running the playbook from WSL by passing our organization hosts details in hosts file of ansible. But WSL(ubantu) login is not configured with our ADS credetails to execute passwordless ssh. But WSL is installed in oganization network. How we can achive this intergration

I tried with gateway host which establish passwordless ssh to connect respective hosts which is defined in ansible hosts file. similar way trying to achive from WSL, created proxy to bypass the connection. But ADS login is blocker for this.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/wsl-debian-gnulinux -OutFile distro.zip -UseBasicParsing
Expand-Archive distro.zip debian
cd distro
.\debian.exe (edited)

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).